# Django REST Framework w/ TokenAuthentication issue with CSRF/CORS

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-csrf, django-cors-headers

I am using TokenAuthentication in Django REST Framework to have a script remotely access my API. The domain running the API is behind a TLS certificate.

I have scoured through MANY sources, and tried many options before coming here to figure out what my problem is. In short, I continue to get the `CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.` error when I attempt to post.

Here is my view:

```
# @csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes((TokenAuthentication,))
@permission_classes((permissions.IsAuthenticated,))
def create_object(request):
```

`csrf_exempt` decorator has done nothing here. So, I have also tried it on my `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^create_object/', csrf_exempt(views.create_object),),
```

I even tried writing a custom decorator, and using [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32404315/1036843). Even when I do this, I cannot even seem to get that decorator to execute before getting the failure. Perhaps there is an issue with the ordering of my middleware?

```
'sslify.middleware.SSLifyMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',

'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',

'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',

'corsheaders.middleware.CorsPostCsrfMiddleware',

'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
```

Here are my django cors settings:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False 
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ('example.com',) 
CORS_REPLACE_HTTPS_REFERER = True
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As promised, here is the solution that I came up with. Admittedly, this is not perfect. I was not able to figure the underlying problem (why on HTTPS the app was not responding to `csrf_exempt`, or `CORS_REPLACE_HTTPS_REFERER`), but came up with this limited solution.

**STEP 1**

First, I subclassed the entire `CsrfViewMiddleware` class into my own version, and placed it into my middleware (changes from original quertion marked):

```
'sslify.middleware.SSLifyMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',

'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',

'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
#'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',    ##CHANGE
'myapp.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',    ##CHANGE

'corsheaders.middleware.CorsPostCsrfMiddleware',

'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
```

At about line 160 of **my version** of `CsrfViewMiddleware`, I replaced the existing conditional to this:

```
            acceptable_referers = ['https://%s' % u for u in settings.CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST] + ['http://%s' % u for u in settings.CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST]
            if not same_origin(referer, good_referer) and referer not in acceptable_referers:
```

This got me past the invalid referer issue, which is fine because I am whitelisting the domains that are okay. It essentially comes to the same result as `CORS_REPLACE_HTTPS_REFERER`. My version cross-references the referer header with `settings.CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST`, while the `CORS_REPLACE_HTTPS_REFERER` method temporarily changes the `request` referer. Neither seems to me a sufficient enough security solution--but that is another conversation.

**STEP 2**

At this point, I was still getting the csrf cookie not found error. To circumvent this problem, and since `csrf_exempt` was not respoding (it seemed as if the middleware was executing too early), I added a new piece of middleware:

```
'sslify.middleware.SSLifyMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',

'myapp.csrf.CsrfSkipMiddleware'    ##ADDED

'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',

'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
#'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',    ##REMOVED
'myapp.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',    ##ADDED

'corsheaders.middleware.CorsPostCsrfMiddleware',

'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
```

This new piece of middleware essentially sets a flag on the request object (`_dont_enforce_csrf_checks`) that already exists on the stock version of `CsrfViewMiddleware` and tells the script to ignore the rest of the csrf check. In order to do that, it checks the page path against a list of paths that I have selected to remove from csrf in `settings.CSRF_SKIP_URLS`.

```
class CsrfSkipMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        CSRF_SKIP_URLS = [re.compile(expr) for expr in settings.CSRF_SKIP_URLS]
        path = request.path_info.lstrip('/')

        if any(m.match(path) for m in CSRF_SKIP_URLS):
            setattr(request, '_dont_enforce_csrf_checks', True)
```

**THOUGHTS**

Again, not the best implementation. But, for my purposes it works. Thoughts are still welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using django cors headers.
I was facing a similar issue and specifying:
`CORS_REPLACE_HTTPS_REFERER = True` in `settings.py` resolved the problem.

Comment: Outdated by now